# Next.js app router + Sanity revalidateTag() issues

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js, vercel, sanity

I’m trying to get next app router + revalidateTag() to work with Sanity but it’s either completely unpredictable or I totally misunderstood something.

I now spent 5 full days trying to make it work and build multiple projects. Here’s what I can tell now:

Project 1: This is the most basic, simple setup (posts, pages, categories, [slug] dynamic pages). I think this works. https://github.com/thedevdavid/sanity-revalidate-debug

Project 2: Almost the same setup (posts, pages, categories, [slug] dynamic pages + subpages with extra tags). Here, the simple tags: [job] or tags: [benefit] requests are never getting revalidated on the / and /post-a-job routes. But in (for example) /contract/[slug] route. And the complex tags, like [job:${params.slug}] or [page:${params.slug}] are all working well.

Projects 3 & 4: Very similar to project 2. posts, pages, and categories with extra schema types, like team members, navigation links, testimonials, and more. Here I can’t even tell the exact problems. Probably similar to project 2 but I’m not sure anymore.

Although there’s 1 thing I know that’s extra. There’s a homepage type with the fetch tag, homepage. This type has the navigation links. There’s a fetch tagged with homepage on (site)/page.tsx and in 2 components (Navbar & Footer). Both components are rendered from (site)/layout.tsx. The fetch from the components gets revalidated and I can see the new data on all pages, except the / route, aka. (site)/page.tsx. That route never gets revalidated. Although the page and 2 components inside have tagged requests.

In all 4 projects, the Sanity webhook calls the revalidate API route. The function always succeeds. Params are what they are supposed to be, so I guess the revalidateTag() gets called with the right parameters. (Although I have not figured out how to debug the actual function calls yet)

Soooo I feel totally lost and I haven’t even tried to include previews and draft mode yet.

I'm not sure if it's a bug with Sanity, Next.js, or it's just me doing something wrong.

#### Additional context

Example fetch call (fails to revalidate, on / route):

```
  const jobs = await sanityFetch<Job[]>({
    query: jobsQuery,
    tags: [`job`],
  });
```

Example fetch call (revalidates. /[slug] route):

```
const page = await sanityFetch<Page>({
    query: pagesBySlugQuery,
    params: { slug: params.slug },
    tags: [`page:${params.slug}`],
  });
```

sanityFetch function:

```
export async function sanityFetch<QueryResponse>({
  query,
  params = DEFAULT_PARAMS,
  tags = DEFAULT_TAGS,
}: {
  query: string;
  params?: QueryParams;
  tags: string[];
}): Promise<QueryResponse> {
  return client.fetch<QueryResponse>(query, params, {
    // We only cache if there's a revalidation webhook setup
    cache: revalidateSecret ? "force-cache" : "no-store",
    next: {
      //revalidate: 30, // for simple, time-based revalidation
      tags, // for tag-based revalidation
    },
  });
}
```

Revalidate route handler:

```
import { revalidateTag } from "next/cache";
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { parseBody } from "next-sanity/webhook";

import { revalidateSecret } from "@/lib/sanity.api";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const { body, isValidSignature } = await parseBody<{
      _type: string;
      slug?: string | undefined;
    }>(req, revalidateSecret);
    if (!isValidSignature) {
      const message = "Invalid signature";
      return new Response(message, { status: 401 });
    }

    if (!body?._type) {
      return new Response("Bad Request", { status: 400 });
    }

    revalidateTag(body._type);
    if (body.slug) {
      revalidateTag(`${body._type}:${body.slug}`);
    }
    return NextResponse.json({
      status: 200,
      revalidated: true,
      now: Date.now(),
      body,
    });
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.error(err);
    return new Response(err.message, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having almost the same setup and similar issue but the opposite way, my dynamic pages never revalidate but my home page is working fine. At one moment i found a solution like this:

[image]

But then after building the app it messed up my whole app. All my dynamic routes were redirecting to 404 until i removed `revalidateTag("page")` line.

Now my pages are not revalidating at all, again! and i'm totally stuck at this moment.

You can try `revalidateTag("your tag")`, probably it can fix your issue.